# Get TreeTableView row from inside a cell?

Tags: java, javafx

```
thisColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn<Obj, String>, TreeTableCell<Obj, String>>() {
    @Override
    public TreeTableCell<Task, String> call(final TreeTableColumn<Task, String> param) {
        JFXComboBox<String> jfxComboBox = new JFXComboBox<>();
        jfxComboBox.setMinWidth(100.0);
        jfxComboBox.setPrefWidth(100.0);
        jfxComboBox.setItems(Class.profiles);

        jfxComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                /** N/A **/
            }
        });
        final TreeTableCell<Task, Void> cell = new TreeTableCell<Task, Void>() {
            HBox hBox = new HBox();
            Boolean result = hBox.getChildren().addAll(jfxComboBox);
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(hBox);
                }
            }
        };
        return cell;
    }
});
```

I'm currently trying to display a JFXComboBox (ComboBox), in a TreeTableView and with the current code, it's adding it. However, in the callback, there's no way that I can access the row that `jfxComboBox` is in.

I noticed that if I use `TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures` instead of TreeTableColumn, it'll give me access to param.getValue().getValue() which is exactly what I need, but then I'm not able to return the TreeTableCell to display my jfxComboBox.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

PS:

I'm trying to avoid using `.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` because when I click on the ComboBox, I'm not selecting the current row yet/will possibly not select any row before clicking on the combo box. But I am interested in seeing if there's a way to trigger a select for the parent row that jfxComboBox is in.

Comment: Do you need `getTreeTableRow().getItem()` ?

Comment: I can only find `param.getTreeTableView().getTreeItem(int)` which I don't have a way of getting any type of index. @Sunflame

Comment: I mean this way: myCol.setCellFactory(param -> {
   TreeTableCell<MyModel,String> tc = new TreeTableCell<>();
   MyModel = tc.getTreeTableRow().getItem();
   return tc;
  });

Comment: Hmm, I'll try that. How would I access param from inside the code block? Thanks! @Sunflame

Comment: For some reason, `tc.getTreeTableRow().getItem()` is always null;

Comment: Hmm.. then you should try to Override the `updateItem()` method an get the Item there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example that can solve your problem:

```
myColumn.setCellFactory(factory -> new TreeTableCell<MyModel, String>(){
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if(empty){
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
                return;
            }
            // if empty is false, then these references should not be null
            MyModel myModel = getTreeTableRow().getItem();
            TreeItem<MyModel> treeItem = getTreeTableRow().getTreeItem();
        }
    });
```